# Using different Redis databases for Spring sessions and custom data

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

In my REST controllers Spring project, I want to store Session information in Redis and my custom information (whatever I need) in Redis also, but in a separate database.

In my *application.properties* I have defined the following:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.session.redis.namespace=rdrestcore
spring.redis.host=192.168.201.46
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.database=5

com.xyz.redis.host=192.168.201.46
com.xyz.redis.db=0
com.xyz.redis.port=6379
com.xyz.redis.pool.min-idle=5
```

I also have a class with the following code (I read somewhere I needed this class just to let Spring administer sessions in Redis... as you can see, it has no code):

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer 
{}
```

I finally have a redis connection factory like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RdRedisConnectionFactory {
    @Autowired 
    private Environment env;
    @Value("${com.xyz.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;
    @Value("${com.xyz.redis.db}")
    private Integer redisDb;
    @Value("${com.xyz.redis.port}")
    private Integer redisPort;
    @Value("${com.xyz.redis.pool.min-idle}")
    private Integer redisPoolMinIdle;

    @Bean
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();        
        if(redisPoolMinIdle!=null) poolConfig.setMinIdle(redisPoolMinIdle);

        return poolConfig;
    }

    @Bean    
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        if(redisHost!=null) jedisConFactory.setHostName(redisHost);
        if(redisPort!=null) jedisConFactory.setPort(redisPort);
        if(redisDb!=null) jedisConFactory.setDatabase(redisDb);
        jedisConFactory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig());
        return jedisConFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate< String, Object > template =  new RedisTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
        template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
        template.setHashValueSerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
        template.setValueSerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
        return template;
    }
}
```

And when I need a Redis read or write, I just autowire *redisTemplate* wherever I need it and it works.

Now... the problem: Spring session info gets stored in the same database as my custom information, although I specified database 5 for session information and database 0 for my custom information. Everything goes to database 0.

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using different bean id for possibly-duplicate bean is a good idea.

```
@Bean    
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {...connection}
```

The above function defined a bean and gave it a default id: `jedisConnectionFactory`, this may replace the one you think spring uses to construct `StringRedisTemplate` (configured by spring.redis.xxx), which also looks for a bean of class JedisConnectionFactory with the same bean id. The result is they both use the definition in `{...connection}`.

BTW: **This is irrelevant** but I noticed you define your own bean by annotation `@Bean` but you didn't use it in a more proper way :

```
@Bean(name="myJedisPool")
JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
}

JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig) {        
    // use spring managed bean.
    jedisConFactory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig);
}

@Bean(name="myRedisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(@Qualifier("myJedisPool") JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig) {
   // use spring managed bean.
    template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory(jedisPoolConfig) );
}
```

Or you found it not useful to have these many beans, so you curtail the amount of beans like this:

```
// not a bean
JedisPoolConfig getJedisPoolConfig() {
}

// not a bean  
JedisConnectionFactory getJedisConnectionFactory() {        
    jedisConFactory.setPoolConfig(getJedisPoolConfig());
}

// only this is bean, because consumers are expecting this.
@Bean(name="myRedisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    template.setConnectionFactory( getJedisConnectionFactory() );
}
```